# Retrieve arguments of current command in tmux pane

Tags: tmux

`{#pane_current_command}` seems to contain only the name of the running executable, without the arguments passed to it. Can the arguments be retrieved in a simple way?

I know of `ps -o state= -o args= -t PANE_TTY`, but I haven't found a way to use the result from within a `tmux` command, such as `set -g pane-border-format "COMMAND_AND_ARGS"`.